# Is displacement of wave $y=A\sin(\omega t-kx)$ or $y=A\sin(\omega t+kx)$?

Tags: waves, coordinate-systems, conventions

I have read online that $\sin(\omega t-kx)$ represents a wave traveling in the positive $x$ direction, and $\sin(\omega t+kx)$ represents a wave traveling in the negative direction. Can someone explain how they represent positive and negative directions?

Comment: Have you tried plotting a few graphs? (BTW  I edited your equations to include the  mathjax typesetting)

Comment: Mike stone is quite right. Pick a value of $k$ and $\omega$ and then plot each function as a function of $x$, first for $t = 0$ and then for $t = 0.1 / \omega$, and then for $t = 0.2/\omega$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you should do:

1. Select any fixed phase, e.g. $0 = \phi = \omega t \pm kx$,
2. Determine the position $x$ of this phase for $t=0$,
3. Increase the time by a "small number" $t=dt$ and check at which position $x$ the selected phase has moved. Hence, in which direction does the wave move?

This can be done either using the formulas or by plotting the function for different times.

Answer (score 1):

you have been provided with theory also you can try this
[applet](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/h64nrfrp)

Comment: Thank you for your answers,i got it,thnkx again

Answer (score 0):

Think about how you might measure the speed of a water wave.

You might well follow a crest and measure how far the crest travels $\Delta x$ in a time interval $\Delta t$.
From those readings you can obtain the speed of the wave $\frac {\Delta x}{\Delta t}$.

For the function that you have chosen a crest means that $\omega t\pm kx = \frac {\pi}{2}+2n\pi $ where $n$ is an integer.
An important thing to note is that if you follow the same crest when you make your measurements $\frac {\pi}{2}+2n\pi $ is constant.
Also $\omega$ and $k$ are positive constants which characterise the wave.

So now lets differentiate $\omega t\pm kx = \frac {\pi}{2}+2n\pi $ with respect to time to obtain $\omega \pm k\frac {dx}{dt} =0 \Rightarrow \frac {dx}{dt} = \color {red}\mp \frac {\omega}{k}$ and note the switch of the signs.

When you started with $\omega t\color{red} - kx = \frac {\pi}{2}+2n\pi $ the velocity of the wave is $\frac {dx}{dt} = \color{red} + \frac {\omega}{k}$ ie travelling in the positive x-direction.

Whereas when you started with $\omega t\color{red} + kx = \frac {\pi}{2}+2n\pi $ the velocity of the wave is $\frac {dx}{dt} = \color{red} - \frac {\omega}{k}$ ie travelling in the negative x-direction.